# Monaco editor not working with Angular v15 - Error: Module not found Error: request argument is not a string

Tags: angular, webpack, monaco-editor

#### Environment

- Angular - `15`
- Node.js - `18.14.0`
- Monaco-Editor - `0.35.0`
- Monaco-Editor-Webpack-Plugin - `7.0.1`

#### Steps to Reproduce

- Install `v0.35.0` of `monaco-editor` in Angular `15` project.
- Install `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin`(currently `7.0.1`).
- Add a custom webpack configuration file:

```
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
        main: './src/main.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "js/[name].[contenthash].js",
        chunkFilename: 'chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js',
        assetModuleFilename: 'media/[name][hash][ext][query]'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    {
                        options: {
                            url: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
            languages: ["typescript", "javascript", "css"]
        })
    ]
};
```

- Do necessary changes in `angular.json`:

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./webpack.config.js",
        "mergeRules": {
          "externals": "replace"
        }
      },
    :
    :
    :
  }
}
```

- Try `ng build`.

#### Errors

Getting the following errors:

```
./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/actionbar/actionViewItems.js:174:0-25 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/actionbar/actionbar.js:479:0-25 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/aria/aria.js:7:0-20 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/button/button.js:147:0-22 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string
./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/checkbox/checkbox.js:147:0-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codiconStyles.js:6:0-31 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codiconStyles.js:7:0-41 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/contextview/contextview.js:146:0-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/countBadge/countBadge.js:54:0-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/dropdown/dropdown.js:146:0-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/dropdown/dropdownActionViewItem.js:170:0-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/findinput/findInput.js:123:0-25 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/findinput/replaceInput.js:147:0-25 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/hover/hoverWidget.js:121:0-21 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/iconLabel/iconLabel.js:223:0-25 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/inputbox/inputBox.js:152:0-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/keybindingLabel/keybindingLabel.js:153:0-31 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/list/listPaging.js:54:0-20 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/list/listWidget.js:572:0-20 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/mouseCursor/mouseCursor.js:5:0-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/progressbar/progressbar.js:123:0-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/sash/sash.js:220:0-20 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/scrollbar/scrollableElement.js:153:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/splitview/splitview.js:227:0-25 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/table/tableWidget.js:167:0-21 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/tree/abstractTree.js:270:0-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/parts/quickinput/browser/quickInput.js:603:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/parts/quickinput/browser/quickInputBox.js:124:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/parts/quickinput/browser/quickInputList.js:480:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/parts/quickinput/browser/quickInputUtils.js:7:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/controller/textAreaHandler.js:190:0-31 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/currentLineHighlight/currentLineHighlight.js:141:0-36 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/decorations/decorations.js:141:0-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/glyphMargin/glyphMargin.js:141:0-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/indentGuides/indentGuides.js:217:0-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/lineNumbers/lineNumbers.js:141:0-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/linesDecorations/linesDecorations.js:141:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/lines/viewLines.js:205:0-25 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/marginDecorations/marginDecorations.js:141:0-33 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/minimap/minimap.js:241:0-23 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/overlayWidgets/overlayWidgets.js:141:0-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/rulers/rulers.js:141:0-22 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/scrollDecoration/scrollDecoration.js:141:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/selections/selections.js:190:0-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/viewCursors/viewCursors.js:205:0-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/widget/codeEditorWidget.js:254:0-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/widget/diffEditorWidget.js:218:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/widget/diffReview.js:462:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/anchorSelect/anchorSelect.js:464:0-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/bracketMatching/bracketMatching.js:220:0-31 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/codeAction/lightBulbWidget.js:184:0-31 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/codelens/codelensWidget.js:77:0-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/colorPicker/colorPickerWidget.js:125:0-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/dnd/dnd.js:143:0-19 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/find/findWidget.js:485:0-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/folding/folding.js:212:0-23 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/gotoError/gotoErrorWidget.js:226:0-37 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/gotoSymbol/link/goToDefinitionAtPosition.js:116:0-40 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/gotoSymbol/peek/referencesWidget.js:603:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/inlineCompletions/ghostTextWidget.js:198:0-25 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/links/links.js:570:0-21 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/message/messageController.js:65:0-33 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/parameterHints/parameterHintsWidget.js:187:0-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/peekView/peekView.js:160:0-36 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/rename/renameInputField.js:112:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/snippet/snippetSession.js:165:0-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/suggestWidget.js:402:0-29 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/unicodeHighlighter/bannerController.js:194:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/unicodeHighlighter/unicodeHighlighter.js:552:0-34 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/zoneWidget/zoneWidget.js:105:0-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/standalone/browser/accessibilityHelp/accessibilityHelp.js:153:0-33 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/standalone/browser/iPadShowKeyboard/iPadShowKeyboard.js:141:0-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/standalone/browser/inspectTokens/inspectTokens.js:153:0-29 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/standalone/browser/quickInput/standaloneQuickInputServiceImpl.js:153:0-36 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/standalone/browser/standaloneEditor.js:5:0-33 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/platform/actions/browser/menuEntryActionViewItem.js:604:0-39 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/platform/contextview/browser/contextMenuHandler.js:56:0-34 - Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string

Error: Module not found: Error: request argument is not a string
```

### Additional Context

Seems like JS files of monaco-editor are not being pre-processed properly. I have tried using `babel-loader`, but got the same errors. May using the correct webpack loader is the solution here, if yes, then which one?

Answer (score 0):

The "request argument is not a string" means a library imports another library using a variable, instead of a string literal. Something like:

```js
const loadLibrary = async (name: string) => Promise<MyClass> {
    const { MyClass } = await import(name);
    return MyClass;
}
```

Tools like Webpack cannot process such imports and throw an error. However, there's nothing wrong with it, just limited handling by the packer, so I never understood why this handled like a real error.

You can ignore the errors or suppress them.

Comment: Do you mean the imports like these are causing problem: `import * as platform from '../../../common/platform.js';`? And it should be like `import * from '../../../common/platform.js';`. Can you give an example in your answer - as to what will work?

Comment: I added an example to the answer, which uses `import`, but it is the same for `require`.

Comment: This issue was resolved. Refer: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3553